# OpenErp : how to change the value of an element in tree view?

Tags: xml, odoo

In OpenErp, how can I give different values ​​for some items in a tree view for example, if I want in the string appears the day of the week:

```
label  string="%%%%A -"
```

shows no errors but only sends me the literal text:

```
%% A
```

What is the correct syntax?

(Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that: you have to overwrite the `fields_view_get` method to change label strings.